# BackgroundMediaPlayer not playing music files outside Music Folder

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8.1, background-process

I am having this strange issue. I am trying to create a music player app for `Windows Phone 8.1`. I need the music player to play the music in background, even if the application is in background/closed state. So I am using the [**BackgroundMediaPlayer**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.media.playback.backgroundmediaplayer) class for playing the music. Following is the code for the same:

```
private void SendMessageToBackground(string Path, string Name, bool IsRadio)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Path))
    {
        var message = new ValueSet();
        message.Add(Constants.TrackURI, Path);
        message.Add(Constants.TrackName, Name);
        message.Add(Constants.IsRadio, IsRadio);
        BackgroundMediaPlayer.MessageReceivedFromBackground += BackgroundMediaPlayer_MessageReceivedFromBackground;
        BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.MediaFailed += Current_MediaFailed;
        BackgroundMediaPlayer.SendMessageToBackground(message);
    }
}
```

The code works all fine, the music is playing smoothly. But now I am facing an issue. I am fetching the music files in the application by looping through all folders. Hence it displays all music files, wherever they are in the folder hierarchy. But when I am trying to play a file outside the `Music` folder created by the windows phone(refer screenshot), the background music player simply doesn't play the file.

[image: Music File Issue]

As seen in the code I am listening to events from the `BackgroundMediaPlayer` and its `MediaPlayer` to check for any possible failure reasons, but both these events are not getting triggered in case of a failed playback. But the `BackgroundMediaPlayer`'s `MessageReceivedFromBackground` event is getting triggered correctly in case of successful playbacks(from Music folder). I checked the file path being passed, and it was all correct, and I tried playing these music files using the inbuilt Music app of the phone, and that too played successfully. What can be the possible problem here? How can I solve it?

**EDIT**

I debugged further and figured out that it is actually an permission issue. The path passed from the above code, I was using in another function, to pass the `Uri`/`StorageFile` to the `BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current`. Code:

```
public async void StartTrackAt(string TrackURI, string Name)
{
    try
    {
        BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SetUriSource(new Uri(TrackURI)); // This works fine in debug mode. Throws Exception in release mode
        /* Tried this also, but this doesn't even work in debug mode
        StorageFile storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(TrackURI);
        mediaPlayer.SetFileSource(s);
        */
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Control comes here when trying to play files outside Music folder.
    }
}
```

I have set the required capabilities in the app's manifest file. But I got the following `Exception` when I tried to run this application:

```
{System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at BackgroundMusicPlayer.MyPlayListManager.<StartTrackAt>d__0.MoveNext()}
    [System.UnauthorizedAccessException]: {System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at BackgroundMusicPlayer.MyPlayListManager.<StartTrackAt>d__0.MoveNext()}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HelpLink: null
    HResult: -2147024891
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"
    Source: "mscorlib"
    StackTrace: "   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at BackgroundMusicPlayer.MyPlayListManager.<StartTrackAt>d__0.MoveNext()"
```

Strangely enough, when passing the `Uri` directly without fetching the `StorageFile`, it works well in debug mode.

Here are the capabilities I have set for the application:

[image: App Capabilities]

Comment: show as the way you use the path in the background audio agent

Comment: @IgorKulman I figured out the actual issue. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with the same access issue for BackgroundMediaPlayer.

Please [see this answer about possible access to different files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33083243/5268585).
So you need to combine FolderPicker and FutureAccessList

```
var folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(folder);
```