# How to unzip file in UWP

Tags: c#, zip, uwp

I'm trying to unzip file, but i always had

> Access to the path 'C:\Users\Kosov Denis\Downloads\12.epub' is
>   denied.

What did i worng?

```
await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(file.Path,
                    ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder.Path +
                    string.Format(@"\{0}", file.Name.Replace(file.FileType, "")));
            });
```

Comment: this is access permission issue in uwp app   [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082835/windows-10-universal-app-file-directory-access) which folders and Directory you can Access.

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered the same problem with you, my google for a long time found UWP seems not directly through the path to access the file, if you want to visit the local file, you need to use the file pickup, see:[hele](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/12/04/skip-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile/).
I used the curve to solve this problem:

```
StorageFolder folder;
folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

//Open the file picker
var _openFile = new FileOpenPicker();
_openFile.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
_openFile.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
_openFile.FileTypeFilter.Add(".zip");
StorageFile file = await _openFile.PickSingleFileAsync();

//Read the file stream
Stream a = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();

//unzip
ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(a);
archive.ExtractToDirectory(folder.Path);
```

[ZipArchive Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/us-en/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx)