# doc.Save("data.xml"); Not working c#

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal

As the headline states, when i try to use doc.Save("data.xml"); it gives me the error "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'

I've tried both of these:

```
public void holder()
    {
        string location = "Employees.xml";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(location);
        XElement person = doc.Element("Person");
        person.Add(new XElement("Employee",
                   new XElement("Name", "David"),
                   new XElement("Dept", "Chef")));
        doc.Save(location);
    }


 public void holder()
    {

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Employees.xml");
        XElement person = doc.Element("Person");
        person.Add(new XElement("Employee",
                   new XElement("Name", "David"),
                   new XElement("Dept", "Chef")));
        doc.Save("Employees.xml");
    }
```

The loading part gives me no problems, its the saving..

Comment: Have you tried without the name of the file, just `doc.Save()`?

Comment: There are no overloads with 0 arguments.

Comment: It should work, XDocument does seem to have an overload for Save accepting a string. Are you using Silverlight by any chance? Review that your reference to System.Xml.Linq is the one you expect.

Comment: I am using Visual studio? Dunno if that is what you mean.. And i dunno about the last part either. I have System.Xml.Linq declared.

Comment: Arh i found something, i am writing a UWA for windows 10. Its in that file that it does not work. When i do it in a console application it all works fine.
Any ideas of how to make it work in a UWA?

Comment: Don't pass it a string and use the stream overload instead?

Comment: I dont know how to do that..

Answer (score 0):

For UWA you need to use the overload [that accepts a stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838476(v=vs.110).aspx), once you get a stream for the file you want to open just pass it in.

public void holder(Stream input, Stream output)
    {

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(input);
    XElement person = doc.Element("Person");
    person.Add(new XElement("Employee",
               new XElement("Name", "David"),
               new XElement("Dept", "Chef")));
    doc.Save(output);
}
```

To see how to get the input and output streams on a UWA program see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082835/windows-10-universal-app-file-directory-access)

Comment: I dont think the post you linked, show how to open or close a filestream?