# How to read and write from file in C# UWA (Universal Windows App)

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am trying to figure out how to read and write files in a UWA application. I  understand that I need to open a FileStreamm, but I can't figure out how to do that.

I started with this code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\XML\test.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
```

seems to work, no red lines.

At the end of all of that I am told to put in `Flush` and `Close`, like this:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\XML\test.txt", FileMode.Create, 

...

fs.Flush();
fs.Close();
```

Now, this is where I hit a snag, because fs.Close(); is not even on the list of functions on `fs`. I just get a red line in my IDE if I try to hardcode it.

Can someone please take the time to help me understand how to do this with UWA? For some reason it seems like there is a different approach in Windows 10 apps, and I have a VERY hard time finding anything that shows me how to do it right. All the tutorials and SOF forum input are about older versions (non-UWA).

When I do this in a console application it all works as expected.

My end goal is to be able to read and write to an XML file in this kind of fashion:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(input);
XElement person = doc.Element("Person");
person.Add(new XElement("Employee",
           new XElement("Name", "David"),
           new XElement("Dept", "Chef")));
doc.Save(output);
```

I'm going down this path because an answer to my previous question told me to use a FileStream, but I simply cannot make that work in UWA.

Comment: Did you try the official docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files

it's number 1 in google search, so I dont think you are using the right keyword. Try "uwp read write file".

This series https://www.tutorialspoint.com/windows10_development/windows10_development_file_management.htm help alots for me. I think you need to add a file picker, pick the needed file, and read it.

Comment: Hey hey hey, you pull the google card already? hehe - I think you are right, i didn't come across this article and must have used the wrong keywords. I guess "Fix my life" and "Make it work = true;" just don't cut it these days.

Comment: I hate the MSDN though, that place is not made for people that don't spend a lot of time programming. How do i make "Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder =" work, where i choose a specifik folkder?

Comment: I tried this, with no luck: public async void WriteFile()
        {
            StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"C:\XML");
            StorageFile sampleFile = await folder.GetFileAsync("test.txt");
            await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, "Cmoooon!");
        }

Comment: Can someone write a full set of code that can write to "c:\XML\test.txt" in UWA. I simply cannot make it work :S

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 Universal App File/Directory Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082835/windows-10-universal-app-file-directory-access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the (simple) solution is to put the xml-file in the PROJECTFOLDER/bin/x86/debug/appX and then write the data to a list this way:

```
public class dataRaw
    {
        public string data { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
    }

    //You can call this class with x = collectionGenerator.getList() (it returns a list<T>)
    public class collectionGenerator
    {
       public static List<dataRaw> getList()
        {
            //This is the xml file in the folder
            var doc = XDocument.Load("Data.xml"); 

            //This parse the XML and adds in to the list "dataList"
            var dataList = doc.Root
                .Descendants("Person")
                .Select(node => new dataRaw
                {
                    //data, firstName and lastName are in app variables from dataRaw put into listData.
                    //Number, FirstName and LastName are the nodes in the XML file.
                    data = node.Element("Number").Value,
                    firstName = node.Element("FirstName").Value,
                    lastName = node.Element("LastName").Value,
                })
            .ToList();
            return dataList;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just access any file from a Universal Windows App. Access to the file system is restricted.

See [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) for details.

To help you further we need to know more about your application. What kind of files do you want to access for what reason?

---

Example on how to read an Xml File, modify it and store it in an Universal app. You need a button with the following Click handler and a TextBox named "TextBoxLog".

```
private async void ButtonDemo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     // Get our local storage folder
     var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

     XmlDocument xmlDocument;

     // Try to get file 
     var file = await localFolder.TryGetItemAsync("MyData.xml") as IStorageFile;

     if(file != null)
     {
          // File exists -> Load into XML document
          xmlDocument = await XmlDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(file);
     }
     else
     {
          // File does not exist, create new document in memory
          xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
          xmlDocument.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>" + Environment.NewLine + "<root></root>");
     }

     // Now show the current contents
     TextBoxLog.Text = "";

     var lEntries = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Entry");
     foreach(var lEntry in lEntries)
     {
          TextBoxLog.Text += lEntry.InnerText + Environment.NewLine;
     }

     // Now add a new entry
     var node = xmlDocument.CreateElement("Entry");
     node.InnerText = DateTime.Now.ToString();
     xmlDocument.DocumentElement.AppendChild(node);

     // If the file does not exist yet, create it
     if(file == null)
     {
          file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("MyData.xml");
     }

     // Now save the document
     await xmlDocument.SaveToFileAsync(file);

}
```

Comment: Okay, well what i really want is to be able to read and write from a XML file so i can make lists, to use with in the app.

Comment: But i don't know if i could just make a in-app list that saves the data in between uses with out xml?

Comment: I guess the reason why i would like to have a XML file, is so i can add data into my app, outside the actual app. So i can access the xml via notepad++, add data that is the usable next time i run the app.

Comment: You can. Type %localappdata% into the address bar of Windows explorer, then search for "MyData.xml" and you will find the file and can edit it with a normal text editor.

Comment: Yeah iv'e just realized that the UWP apparently is a bit restricted with writing to local files in what ever folder you choose. So you are somewhat (at least what i get now) forced to use their "in app file system" and then just work around it on the outside..

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time. Non of the guides i have found so far have looked like this. I will look into it when i get back up tomorrow, with a clear head.

Comment: Hurraaa :D i made it work. Now it just need to make sense of it all, but FINALLY i got some text into an xml file :D
oh btw, juust in case someone with the lack of skills like me arrives in here. either REMOVE 'Using System.xml' or putin Windows.Data.Xml.Dom. infront of all the xmldocument.

Comment: You cant access to whatever file without user's consent. You only have full access to your local sandbox folder for your app. You need to ask user to pick a file using FilePicker to have access to file at other location (but you do have access to some other specific place, but not as freely as your sandbox)