# Universal Windows Platform App with google calendar

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Hey im trying to make an Universal Windows Platform App where google calendar is in it, but i cant figure out how to convert the code, i got the code to work on a WPF App.
I am not the best at coding https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet this is the site i use as a guideline in the start if its to any help, any help?
Code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

namespace Test1UWA
{
    class GoogleEvents4
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    }

    class GoogleClass4
    {
        public List<GoogleEvents4> GoogleEvents = new List<GoogleEvents4>();

        static string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly };
        static string ApplicationName = "Google Calendar API .NET Quickstart";



        public GoogleClass4()
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                            new FileStream("client_secret4.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

            }
            // Create Google Calendar API service.
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Define parameters of request.
            EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
            request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
            request.ShowDeleted = true;
            request.SingleEvents = true;
            request.MaxResults = 10;
            request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

            // List events.
            Events events = request.Execute();
            if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
                {
                    string when = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString();
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(when))
                    {
                        when = eventItem.Start.Date;
                    }

                    GoogleEvents.Add(new GoogleEvents4 { Title = eventItem.Summary, StartDate = eventItem.Start.DateTime, EndDate = eventItem.End.DateTime });


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Convert the code"? I'm not seeing anything WPF or UWP-specific in the example you posted. What problem are you having, *exactly*?

Comment: my problem is GetFolderPath, SpecialFolder and FileDataStore is not available in UWP

Comment: You will want to use the UWP Filesystem API instead, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082835/windows-10-universal-app-file-directory-access

Comment: To my knowledge UWP isn't supported by the client library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time the Google .net Client library does not support UWP.

Link from the [client library (supported platform list)](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/pull/852)

> chrisdunelm 27 days ago Google member Unfortunately we don't support
>   UWP yet, so it can't be on the list yet. Maybe we should highlight
>   that we don't support it :(

Update:

> We plan to support UWP in the v2.0 release, which we hope will be early 2017.