# Drag&Drop File Attribute is ReadOnly

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, uwp, win-universal-app

I created an Attached Property which registers the drag and drop events and requests the operations: move, link, copy.

```
        UIElement dragablecontrol = d as UIElement;
        if (dragablecontrol != null)
        {
            dragablecontrol.AllowDrop = true;
            dragablecontrol.DragEnter += Dragablecontrol_DragEnter;
            dragablecontrol.DragStarting += Dragablecontrol_DragStarting;//does not get fired
            dragablecontrol.DragOver += Dragablecontrol_DragOver; //e.AcceptedOperation got move, link, copy
            dragablecontrol.Drop += Dragablecontrol_Drop; //e.DataView.RequestedOperation is set none
        }
```

Anyway the starting drag event is not fired and my RequestedOperation are ignored because `e.Data` is null in drag enter.

Therefore (I guess) the event argument parameter `e.DataView.RequestedOperation` is set to `None` in the drop event. The file attributes I get with `var filesAndFolders = await e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync();` are set to `ReadOnly`.

What can I do about that. I need to rename the dragged files. I created a demo project on [GitHub](https://github.com/mfe-/Get.the.solution.UWP.XAML/blob/master/Core/OnDrag.cs).

Comment: Have you gone through this: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop

Comment: The sample only shows how to handle drag and drop internal in the application. Not related with files.

Comment: This is by design, dropped files to a uwp app are readonly.

Comment: Is there any source to verify that dropped files to a uwp app are readonly @MehrzadChehraz ?

Comment: @Briefkasten I don't have one, but pretty sure that this is it. There is also a request posted [here](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/10911696-universal-apps-drag-drop-remove-read-only-attr) by developers asking to remove this restriction.