# Is there Any way to Run UWP Application with Administrator Rights?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have created an application using Windows Universal Platform Tools in Visual Studio. In this application I have to rename files selected by user, but I am getting Permission denied exception while debugging.

After packing it & installing on machine I am not getting option to run it as administrator.

I have searched as much as I could but there doesn't seem to be any solution available on internet or I missed any query that could possibly solve this issue.

I can't see any type of permissions related to Storage as well in manifest file :(

Code:
(Edit: This is now working Code)

```
            FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
        folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
        folderPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
        StorageFolder folderPicked = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

        if (folderPicked != null)
        {

            t_output.Text = folderPicked.Path.ToString();
            StringBuilder outputText = new StringBuilder();
            IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList =
            await folderPicked.GetFilesAsync();
            int i=0;
             foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
            {
                outputText.Append(file.Name + "\n");
                StorageFile fs = await folderPicked.GetFileAsync(file.Name);
                await fs.RenameAsync("tanitani0" + i + ".jpg");
                i++;

            }
```

I am using t_output.Text TextBox to verify each & everything is going as I expect, if I don't use File.Copy then every file is being listed from the selected folder just like I want. But getting Permission Denied issue with File.Copy :( if I directly Use File.Move I am getting File Not Found Exception then.

What can be the way to solve this type of problem?

Comment: Anyone giving -1 if you could tell me the solution as well? :)

Comment: What files are you trying to rename?

Comment: NineBerry Sir, I am testing on image files, but any type of file will be renamed when user wants to i.e. text files, video files, etc.

Comment: Show the source code and also add the project settings of the uwp project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 Universal App File/Directory Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082835/windows-10-universal-app-file-directory-access)

Comment: I have uploaded the Code @NineBerry Sir, in the given link the answer says we can access files from the folder selected by user using FolderPicker. That's exactly what I want to do but still getting Permission Denied exception.

Comment: You don't specify the target folder for copying files

Comment: Thanks NineBerry Sir, I just tried giving target path as well, but still I am getting same permission denied exception;
                      
{ File.Copy(file.Path, folderPicked.Path+@"\tani"+i+".jpg"); }

                       { File.Copy(file.Path, folderPicked.Path+"tani"+i+".jpg"); }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few filesystem limitations in UWP, and you just ran into one of them. By getting access to the folder, you have to continue using that `StorageFolder` instance to make modifications.

To create a copy of the file, use `folderPicked.CreateFileAsync(path)` and use that `StorageFile` returned from that method to copy the stream data. But since you have access to the individual files inside the directory, you can take advantage of the `StorageFile` interface and perform your operations asynchronously. Here's a list of methods permitted:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile

Using `File.Copy(...)` will only work in your isolated storage / application data directories. Just because you have `folderPicked` does not mean `File.Copy(...)` has access.

Code sample:

```
foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
{
    outputText.Append(file.Name + "\n");
    int i = 0;

    await file.CopyAsync(pickedFolder, "tani" + i + ".jpg");
    i++;
}
```

On a side note, your `int i` value will always be zero. Just make sure it's outside the loop to continue incrementing.

```
int i = 0;

foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
{
    outputText.Append(file.Name + "\n");        
    await file.CopyAsync(pickedFolder, "tani" + i + ".jpg");
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Laith Sir :D This worked ^_^ I created StorageFile object & renamed it using the builtin function :D (yes sir I noticed afterwards while rename method worked & I was getting error)