# UWP Binding image from local folders

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

My app takes a photo using the Camera and saves it like this C:\Users...\Pictures\file.PNG. I have an object with string "C:\Users\...\Pictures\file.PNG" and binding set to that string, but it does not load the Image. If i place the image to Assets and set the string to "Assets\file.png" it works. Is it possible to bind outside of Assets?

Comment: What kind of UI control are you using to display image?

Comment: <Image Width="150" Source="{x:Bind Obrazek }" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Image>

Comment: You can bind Source directly to some BitmapImage, but I suggest that you first take closer look on how to handle files in UWP and how camera works (in my Answer below) and then you can elaborate more on Binding. I am not saying that what you're trying to do is impossible (it is possible for SURE), just take it step-by-step.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to realize that you **do not** have access to file system as e.g. in Win32 apps. So the full path in UWP app is not relevant anymore. Please take a look on this [link to explain it more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) and [nice one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082835/windows-10-universal-app-file-directory-access).

I assume you're using `Image` control to display image. Something like:

> MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Loaded="MainPage_OnLoaded">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Image Name="Img1" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

> MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    private async void MainPage_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var file = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.CameraRoll.GetFileAsync("p1.png");
        using (var imgStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        {
            var bitmapImg = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImg.SetSource(imgStream.AsRandomAccessStream());
            Img1.Height = bitmapImg.PixelHeight; //Need to take care of proper image-scaling here
            Img1.Width = bitmapImg.PixelWidth;  //Need to take care of proper image-scaling here
            Img1.Source = bitmapImg;
        }
    }
```

When you understand file-access concept files in UWP, you can take closer look on built-in [camera control support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-photos-and-video-with-cameracaptureui). There's also example how to directly access captured image without hassling with file names.