# Why can’t I access the DownloadsFolder from my Xamarin.Forms UWP application, getting a System.UnauthorizedAccessException?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

My Xamarin.Forms UWP application needs to save files on the user’s device. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#users-downloads-folder) says a UWP the application can access the appropriate folder created inside the usual “Downloads” folder. However, when I try to save a file there using the `DownloadsFolder` class, I get the following exception:

```
Access to the path 'C:\Users\tikoz\Downloads\38b8dad0-9c00-4b76-8f23-59192c50b740_enn3pya30cxd2!App\tff20210219204840.jpg' is denied.
```

The code I use to download a file is the following:

```
try {
   var checkAlreadyExistingFile = await Windows.Storage.DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);

   var share = new ShareClient(StorageAccountConnectionString, FileShareName);
   var directory = share.GetDirectoryClient(string.Empty);
   var file = directory.GetFileClient(fileName);

   ShareFileDownloadInfo download = await file.DownloadAsync();
   using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(checkAlreadyExistingFile.Path)) { // Raises the exception
      await download.Content.CopyToAsync(stream);
      DownloadedReceiptImagePath = stream.Name;
      return DownloadedReceiptImagePath;
   }
}
catch (Exception e) {
   Console.WriteLine(e);
   return null;
}
```

I want to download files saved in Azure File Shares. The `catch` clause catches the exception mentioned above, raised by the `File.OpenWrite(checkAlreadyExistingFile.Path` instruction. Do I misunderstand the docs, or do I miss something?

Comment: I think you'd have to include something in Package.appxmanifest file to access downloads folder

Comment: @ShubhamTyagi I didn’t find anything related to that file in the docs about the `DownloadsFolder`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082835/windows-10-universal-app-file-directory-access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to download files saved in Azure File Shares. The catch clause catches the exception mentioned above, raised by the File.OpenWrite(checkAlreadyExistingFile.Path instruction.

Please check `DownloadsFolder` [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.downloadsfolder?view=winrt-19041#file-and-folder-permissions-in-the-downloads-folder) here. Capabilities are not needed to create or access files in the Downloads folder. But you need use `Windows Storage` Api but not `System.IO`(`OpenWrite`). You could get steam for writing like the following.

```
var checkAlreadyExistingFile = await Windows.Storage.DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync("Test", CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);

using (var stream = await checkAlreadyExistingFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{ 
    // process stream here.
}
```